# Will Go GC attempted to free an "external heap" from unsafe.Pointer in a reflect.SliceHeader struct?

Tags: arrays, go, garbage-collection, cgo

So I found out how to create a slice from an unsafe pointer in Go:

```
func cArray2ByteSlice(array unsafe.Pointer, len int) (list []byte) {
    sliceHeader := (*reflect.SliceHeader)((unsafe.Pointer(&list)))
    sliceHeader.Cap = len
    sliceHeader.Len = len
    sliceHeader.Data = uintptr(array)
    return list
}
```

I have a window of opportunity to access the heap memory at `array unsafe.Pointer` between calling the external C API `lock` and `unlock`.

The GC will eventually attempt to collect the slice `list []byte`.
The thing is:  the slice header is in golang allocated heap, but the `sliceHeader.Data` is not.

Is the GC smart enough to ignore none-golang heap allocation in that situation, as in most others?

After calling `unlock`, I want to be sure that Go GC doesn't attempt to release the heap memeory at `sliceHeader.Data`.

Also if I want to copy the data for use outside of the `lock`/`unlock` period, I assume I could return this var instead:

```
 var safeList []byte = list[:]
```

Comment: I've never played too much with the GC specifically as it relates to cgo, but note that the slice header and the underlying array are two entirely separate memory allocations.  Slice headers can and often are GC'd without the underlying array being GC'd because that array is still referenced somewhere else.  So there's no reason to expect the underlying data to necessarily be GC'd just because the slice header is.  It's also worth noting that the slice header in this case is almost certainly allocated on the stack, since it is returned as a copy (ie. not as a `*[]byte`).